# How to extract word count group by day for twitter?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get a table which shows the count of the number of tweets(records/rows) each day from tweet DB(.tsv file) which were collected tweets based on a word.

However, I could not get the result.

What problem?

(The .tsv file size collected tweet was 400MB in this trial, which term is 2020/7/21-2021/7/14. I want to process to over 1GB of tweet DB.)

```py
df = pd.read_table("my_collect_tweets.tsv", sep="\t", dtype={"id_str": str, "user.id_str": str,  "full_text": object}, 
parse_dates=[2] #column2 was readed as datetime64 type
)
print(df)
```

|  | `id_str` | `user.id_str` | `created_at` | `full_text` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1282896204020342785 | C | 2020-07-14 04:34:24 | full_text.. |
| 1 | 1284360684835180544 | B | 2020-07-18 05:33:44 | full_text... |
| 2 | 1282819186658443264 | A | 2020-07-13 23:28:22 | full_text... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

```
>>> print(f"dtype:\n{df.dtypes}")
dtype:
id_str                 object
user.id_str            object
created_at     datetime64[ns]
full_text              object
dtype: object
```

- Below were trial result to count record each month or day.

```
df.groupby(['created_at',df.created_at.dt.month])
```

- result `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x1aa614130>`

```
df3=df.groupby(df['created_at'].map(lambda x: x.month))
df3
```

- result `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x1a6f4b460>`

```
df.groupby(df.created_at.dt.month)
```

- Not completed in 400 minutes, continuously processing.

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="created_at", freq="D")).sum()
```

- Not completed in 400 minutes, continuously processing.

---

- Added below at 2022.04.28

```
# reduced columns
df = df[["id_str","created_at"]]
df.head()
```

```
>>>print(f"dtype:{df.dtypes}"
dtype:id_str                object
created_at    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

```
import datetime as dt
df[(df['created_at'] >= dt.datetime(2020,11,1)) & (df['created_at'] < dt.datetime(2020,11,16))
```

- The above result was what I expected.

```
df.query('"2020-12-1" <= created_at <= "2020-12-31"')
```

- The above result was what I expected.

```
df['created_at'].dt.month
```

- The above code resulted to below. All values of month column was 7.0. Is this correct?

```
0           7.0
1           7.0
2           7.0
3           7.0
4           7.0
           ... 
13263129    7.0
13263130    7.0
13263131    7.0
13263132    7.0
13263133    7.0
Name: created_at, Length: 13263134, dtype: float64
```

```
df2=df.groupby(df['created_at'].dt.month)
df2.head()
```

- The above command resulted what I did not expect. The below did not classified each month.

```
    id_str  created_at
0   1282896204020342785 2020-07-14 04:34:24
1   1284360684835180544 2020-07-18 05:33:44
2   1282819186658443264 2020-07-13 23:28:22
3   1284262037783109632 2020-07-17 23:01:44
4   1282643078205992960 2020-07-13 11:48:34
... ... ...
12984031    1388282015129079808 2021-05-01 00:00:00
12984032    1388282018618765315 2021-05-01 00:00:00
12984033    1388282028185899009 2021-05-01 00:00:03
12984034    1388282033349165058 2021-05-01 00:00:04
12984035    1388282045407784960 2021-05-01 00:00:07
65 rows × 2 columns
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Does it word with a small input?

Comment: This content was exact excluding the contents of column full_text, the column user.id_str.

Comment: if you want to group by day then why you use `dt.month` ? It should be `dt.date`. And if you have big data then maybe yoh sould first create dataframe only two columns - date (without time), text - and later work with thid dataframe. You may need also split it to smaller parts and run in separated threads, or use modules which can work with multiprocessing. OR maybe you need faster computer - i.e. [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com)

Comment: Thank your advices. I re-tried to g-colab from my jupyter. However That did not work(?).

Comment: I Added additional result on 2022.4.28 after first post manuscript.